# Altering display mode for authoring information

Tags: entities

I'm trying to deal with authoring info for articles in Drupal 7. I've found the way to hide or unhide it, and that's all I can do. But what I'd need is find a way to display on certainly tagged articles, but hide when that specific tag is not added. Is there any solution for this without coding? CSS is okay, but I know no PHP.

Thank,
cs.

Comment: No, there's no way to do that without coding (unless you can find a module that happens to implement the exact functionality you're looking for)

Answer (score 0):

As you prefer css, checkout the module [Field Formatter CSS Class](http://drupal.org/project/field_formatter_css_class)

> The Field formatter CSS class module allows you to set any
>   text/list/option/taxonomy field to render as CSS class on the node.
>   This enables the node author to select predefined CSS styling per
>   node.

Also [Field Formatter Class](http://drupal.org/project/field_formatter_class)

> This module allows site administrators to add classes to the outer
>   HTML wrapper for any field display.

Then you can hide your info with css based on this unique class provided by either of these two modules

Comment: That doesn't seem to help me. :\
I'd need something to create class for articles depending on their tags. With this I couldn't find the way to do it.